# Proving the easy direction of Steinitz's theorem.

Tags: graph-theory

Long time lurker here, first time poster. I am trying to prove that the graph of a convex polyhedron is 3-connected, as a homework problem.

So far I know that every convex polyhedron has a tetrahedron as a minor, and I think I also know that every vertex of a convex polyhedron has at least degree 3. I am unable to put together a proof using this information though, and I feel as if there must be some fact about convex polyhedra that I simply am not aware of.

Can anyone provide a hint or some advice?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you with my first answer, it was a complete rubbish. Hopefully I got it right this time.

Comment: One approach to answering this is to use facts about graphs of (convex) d-polytopes when d is 3 or more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of a proof:

Given a vertex $v$, all edges not containing $v$ of all faces containing $v$ form a simple cycle in the graph and any edge containing $v$ has the other vertex on that circle.

Now we remove 2 arbitrary vertices and consider any simple path between some other 2 vertices. There are 4 cases:

- No removed vertices were lying on the path
- Only one of the removed vertices was lying on the path
- Both vertices are lying on the path and are not next to each other
- Both vertices are lying on the path and are next to each other.

Show that you can still connect the vertices by some path. Use the fact that vertices connected to the removed ones lie on the correspondent circles.
For the last one show that the circles intersect.

Comment: I think the OP asked how to prove that the graph of a convex polyhedron is 3-connected and planar. Unfortunately, I don't see the connection with the theorem in your answer. Does it really refer to it? Can you make it a bit easier or point to a resource containing the proof?

Comment: @user4205580 I don't understand your comment. OP didn't ask for planarity and I think this is a pretty clear sketch of the proof, the details are easy to fill in. The hidden assumption is that the graph is connected, which shouldn't be a problem.